# Provide suggestions in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, autosuggest

I want my combo box to drop down and provide suggestions when the user types in the combo box.

For example, if the user types "R", then all items starting with "R" (say Roshan, Rohan, Rishan, etc.) should be suggested.

I can get the data from the DB, but the thing is how to drop down the Combo box?

Answer (score 10):

Look the propeties of `comboBox`

```
AutoCompleteMode = Suggest;
AutoCompleteSource = ListItems;
```

Comment: +1. Be aware of the possibility that the `ComboBox` drop-down is displaying when you start typing, however. The drop-down list will steal mouse focus despite being in the background. I usually set `DroppedDown` to `false` in the `KeyDown` event handler when I enable autocomplete.

Comment: im now ok with dropdown i wrote it to keypressed event but when i type a leteer in combo box the curser goes to the left corner of the combo box let say i want to type "uthi" when i pressed "u" curser goes to left corner of the combo box after typing "uthi" it in combo box like "ihut" can u do some suggetions to avoid this?

Comment: you can create another question for that and show your codes. and i think your problem is already solved in my answer, you can check as accepted. thanks :)

Comment: Yes, this answer is the best thing I was looking for all this time. thank you @spajce